# Python Telnet script

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, cisco-ios, getpass

Thanks to [Python Library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html) i was able to use their example to telnet to Cisco switches, I am using this for learning purposes, specifically learning python.

However, although all the code seem generally easy to read, I am a bit confused as to the following:

1- why use the if statement below
2- why use the "\n" after the username and password write method
3- why am i not getting the output on my bash terminal when the changes are infact committed and successful

```
HOST = "172.16.1.76"
user = raw_input("Enter your Telnet username : ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST) 

tn.read_until("Username: ") 
tn.write(user + '\n')                <----- 2
if password:                         <----- 1
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")        <------2
tn.write("show run \n") 

time.sleep(5)



output = tn.read_all()              <----- 3
print output  

print "=" * 30
print "Configuration Complete."
```

I am not sure as to why using the if statement above, typically once you input in the Username, you get the password prompt right afterward. why cant we just type :

```
tn.read_until("Username: ") 
tn.write(user + '\n')
tn.read_until("Password: ")
tn.write(password + "\n")
```

As for the second point, why use the '\n' after the passwords and username in the write method if we going to hit enter after we add them anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: the line

```
password = getpass.getpass()
```

asks you for you password, if you leave it empty, password will contain the empty string which, in an if statement, is the same as False
the script doesn't know ahead of time if you have a password on your server or not, it simulates knowing by asking you first and if you don't input anything, it assumes it doesn't (otherwise it would get stuck on `tn.read_until("Password: ")` forever.

2: the `'\n'` simulates you hitting the return key. when you enter your password, for example `'password<RETURN>'` the variable password will not contain a trailing newline (\n), this is why it is manually appended

3: this one i dont know, possibly 5 seconds isn't enough time to wait

Comment: ok, i think i got it. Thank you! so bascialt "IF statement"  is returning the prompt to enter the password and if you do, it makes it true then looks for the password field in the device prompt and enter the input'ted (such word?) password. correct?      as for the "\n", i still have to hit enter manually though after i input the username and password, i would have though that the "\n" would take care of this for me.

Comment: notice that the script asks you for you password way before the telnet connection. if you just hit enter, the password will be empty. when you hit the line with the `if` it checks to see if the password is empty, if it ISN'T empty, the script will look at the telnet output to see when it requests the password and then send it. if it IS empty, the script assumes telnet will not ask for a password.

Answer (score 0):

After execute
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
you have created a telnet channel from your machine to HOST. But you still need to communicate with HOST to push/send your commands and receive the outputs.

To push your commands to HOST, you need to execute tn.write("your_commands_or_input \n"), \n means newline/return, which tells your current commands need to be executed now. After the execution, HOST return the result, which will be caught by your telnet object "tn" and saved in its "local cache", you can search any keywords you expected in this cache by using tn.read_until method, if the expected keyword has been found, read_until will stop(always stop on the 1st found), and you can do anything you need(It's your turn now), else the read_until will keep waiting the output from HOST(Haven't you turn yet). Finally if you want to check all output have been cached, you can execute tn.read_all().

Remember some of the HOST using different login output, i.e Username vs username or Password vs password, you better to use regular expression to match them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a python library on github, specifically for telneting to cisco devices.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/sergeyzelyukin/cisco-telnet.git

import ciscotelnet
with ciscotelnet.CiscoTelnet(host, verbose = False) as cisco:
  if cisco.login(final_mode=CiscoTelnet.MODE_ENABLE, user="john", user_pass="12345678", enable_pass="cisco"):
  # if cisco.login(final_mode=CiscoTelnet.MODE_ENABLE, line_pass="abcdef", enable_pass="cisco"):
    print cisco.cmd("sh int status | inc Fa0/1") 
    print cisco.conf(["interface fast0/1", "descr blank", "load-interval 300"])  
    print cisco.wr()
```